# How to create a LUIS Application

Tags: botframework, bots, azure-bot-service

I do not understand the difference between creating a LUIS App from https://www.luis.ai/ and creating it directly from my azure.

I created a bot application in visual studio. I have tested this app using the Bot Emulator. I now want the app to talk so i thought the best approach is LUIS. I can create a LUIS app directly from the LUIS website, but i do not understand why would you create it in Azure?

Very new to this as you probably can tell!

Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LUIS is a product for Natural Language Processing, it has its website https://www.luis.ai/ (or https://eu.luis.ai/ for Europe endpoints) and needs some parameters to work, for example a consumption key. These **keys** are created on the Azure portal.

You can use LUIS for many type of projects, but one of the main use is inside of a Bot project, hence the possibility to create a **Bot with LUIS template** in Azure portal. That's only creating a bot with an already developed feature to call a LUIS project, but you still have to create and administrate your LUIS project from LUIS portal.

Answer (score 2):

The LUIS website is where you build and manage your LUIS apps. The reason you can create an endpoint for LUIS in the Azure Portal is to be able to get a paid tier of the API or to scale up or down the service. This will generate the keys and an endpoint you can use when connecting your app to another service, such as the [Bot Framework](https://dev.botframework.com/).

The documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-azure-subscription) helps to show what all you get if you create a LUIS endpoint within the portal.

Answer (score 1):

For dev and testing purpose, you may skip creating a Luis service on Azure portal. And rely totally on the key you got from the Luis website. In this case, you will get 1000 api calls free per month. **But what to do when your free quota expires?**

Then, you will have to come to Azure portal to create a Luis service to get new key.

Answer (score 0):

It is very important to understand that a LUIS resource in Azure and a LUIS app in luis.ai are two different things with different purposes and they are to be used in conjunction with each other. You can't just pick one or the other.

Think of luis.ai as your development space where the AI portion of your LUIS app is created and tested. Azure is all about hosting and pricing, so that's where the app you created in luis.ai gets published to. Once you have a working LUIS app it needs a place on the Internet to live so client applications can hit its endpoint, and Azure provides server space for that purpose.

It's just like building a website locally using Visual Studio or any other tool. It's not good enough to just have a local project if you want other people to be able to see the website. You need a server to host the website on. That's why you need the Azure resource.